# Invisible Stage/Scene in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, visibility, scene

I'm looking for a way to hide a JavaFX Stage or Scene. Now I know about `.hide()`, but that won't work. I need something that still keeps the window, but just makes it completely transparent. A good analogy is `display: none` and `visibility: hidden` in CSS. Whereas the first completely and totally removes a tag/node from the screen, the second just makes it invisible. I'd like something like `visibility` in JavaFX, not display (which is the hide and show methods). It also might help that my stage decoration is set to TRANSPARENT. That should make things a little easier.

I've already tried moving the stage off the screen, but that makes the whole program do some unexpected things. It throws a lot of errors that it clearly shouldn't.

One more thing: If it's possible, I'd like to be able to move/interact with the window, even though you can't see it. If this is too hard, that's okay. Its not really necessary.

Comment: What is the purpose of keeping the window rather than .hide()?

Comment: Two reasons, actually. The first being that this needs to happen instantly. hide can take a couple milliseconds and is done partially asynchronously (as I learned the hard way). The seconds being that things like animations get restarted and some GUI-related logic is put on hold. I need everything to pretend that the window is still visable, when you can't see it. I need an elegant method to see what's behind my stage. hide() is extremely obtrusive and seems entirely unnecessary.

Comment: @TilakMadichetti I believe the syntax is `stage.initStyle(...)` without the word `set` in the method name per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#initStyle-javafx.stage.StageStyle-

Comment: Oh yeah ! thanks !! Sorry - I'll correct it. @QZSupport

Comment: You can also use stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT); for stage and for scene initialize it like new Scene(root, 300, 420, Color.TRANSPARENT);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using toBack() on your Stage.

Comment: What if the desktop is visible? Other than that, it works fine.

Comment: @Taconut If the desktop is visible then you're back to your original problem, using hide().

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, and it worked great! I had to set up a TimeLine, though. With a 15ms interval.