# JavaFx, Not to display content at the beginning

Tags: java, javafx

I am writing a javafx program, for moving text. The program display the background (some red points) and text at the beginning.

Now, I would like to add a menu to select the content of text to display. In addition, I want the scene to display nothing at the beginning, then after I select content of text, the program starts to display everything...

Is there any special command to implement this?

PS: I add the contents (text and shapes) -> "Group" -> "root".

Comment: I think you will need to do it with listeners on your menu. This post could help you to hide your content : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097086/invisible-stage-scene-in-javafx

Comment: @romfret, thank you very much for the link. I just read the tutorial, http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#close(). But the ".toBack()" can only be applied to the stage, and it throws errors when I try to apply this command to my contents (shapes and text added to "Group").

Comment: Do you have a menu? show us the code. If you want to hide something, for example the layout with controls then use e.g `borderPane.setVisible(false);` and vice-versa. Also you need listener to menu action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is something along this:

```
public class PersonOverviewController implements Initializable{

    @FXML 
    BorderPane paneWithControls;
    @FXML
    MenuItem menuItem;
    @FXML
    Label text;



    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        paneWithControls.setVisible(false); //hide content
        menuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() { //implementing action listener
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                text.setText("Some text you want to display"); //set value for controls
                paneWithControls.setVisible(true); //display content
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

If you really want to "hide" the scene you can do something like this:

```
primaryStage.setScene(null);
```

and later on:

```
primaryStage.setScene(sceneObject1);
```

However this is not good way to achieve result you are looking for. Once you have the scene, just change the root of it, or set properties of it's controls. I have mistaken this also when I was learning JavaFX.

Comment: thank you for your reply. This is exactly what I want to do! However, I create my scene using "Scene" rather than "BorderPane": "Scene  s1= new Scene(root,800, 600, Color.BLACK); ".  I just googled but not found similar commands for "Scene"...

Comment: @SuperDelta [Scene](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html) and [BorderPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html) are completely two different things and are not interchangeable.